# Curve embedding in $\mathbb{P}^3$ - role of divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm following a course in algebraic geometry and have a question about the fact that every non-singular curve can be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$. You should be aware that I have almost no background in algebraic geometry. When I assume that the curve $X$ lies already in some $\mathbb{P}^m$ it is doable. It is done by taking a point $P \in \mathbb{P}^m \backslash X$ outside the curve and project the curve from the point onto a hyperplane $H \cong \mathbb{P}^{m-1}$, this works when $m \geq 4$. The conditions $P$ has to fulfil are the following:

1. $P$ is not on any secant line of $X$,
2. $P$ is not on any tangent line of $X$.

By my very limited background it is hard to understand many things from the book of Hartshorne. Does anyone has a good reference on this subject? I would also like to ask what divisors and linear systems precisely do and how they come into play?

**Note:** This is a follow-up to [a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334868/example-of-a-curve-embedding-in-mathbbp3) on the same subject. The new question is specifically about the role of **divisors** in this construction. This issue was raised, but not addressed, in the comments beneath an answer in the previous post, which is why it is asked as a separate question here.

Comment: Did you try Griffiths and Harris? They are much more geometric than Hartshorne.

Comment: I've looked at it, but it seems they use a more differential geometry approach. I also couldn't find the topic in my question.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to look at the book "An Invitation to Algebraic Geometry" by Smith, Kahanpää, Kekäläinen and Traves. In page 118, they give a really nice geometric proof that every non-singular curve can be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^3$. This is the first section of Chapter 8, which is all about maps to the projective space, and how it is related to line bundles.

Answer (score 1):

An affine curve is $f(x, y) = 0$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Its normalization is nonsingular by basic commutative algebra. Find your own reference.

Any projective curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ is the union of standard affine pieces. You can take the normalization of each of these affine pieces separately, say$$\widetilde{C}_i \to C_i.$$Given the affine normalization $\widetilde{C}_i$, you can put it in $\mathbb{P}^{N_i}$ in any stupid way. Then the fiber product of all these $\widetilde{C}_i$ is contained in product $\mathbb{P}^{N_i}$ Segre product in $\mathbb{P}^M$—much bigger$$M = \prod (N_i + 1) - 1$$or something. The birational component is then nonsingular, because it has affine pieces dominating each of the $\widetilde{C}_i$. This proof is given somewhere in Shafarevich's book on algebraic geometry.