# A proof that every algebraic curve embeds in $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-space

I am following section 4 of chapter 1 of Griffiths-Harris, "Principles of Algebraic Geometry", and I want to prove that every algebraic curve embeds in $\mathbb{P}^3(\mathbb{C})$. If you know a simple proof of this fact, I would also appreciate a reference to that. Anyway, the book defines the $\textit{chordal variety}$ (denoted with $C(V)$) of an algebraic variety $V \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ as

$\textit{the union of all the lines that meet V twice and the lines tangent to V}$.

Then, it is stated that $C(V)$ is the image of the projection on the third factor of the closure of the *incidence correspondence*,  $I\subset \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n \times \mathbb{P}^n$, defined as
$$I=\{(p,q,r)| p \neq q \in V, p\wedge q \wedge r=0\}.$$
I am not sure I've understood the definition of incidence correspondence (I mean, those conditions look pretty obscure), but for sure I've not understood why $C(V)$ is the image of the closure of $I$ under the projection on the third factor. Any help (also references) will be appreciated.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2334868/example-of-a-curve-embedding-in-mathbbp3).

Comment: What you've written makes no sense. The correct condition is that $p,q,r$ are collinear, which can be interpreted as the algebraic condition that the wedge product of three vectors representing the points $p$, $q$, and $r\in\Bbb P^n$ is zero (i.e., the three vectors are linearly dependent). This condition is independent of choice of representatives.

Comment: 1. It is not true that every curve embeds in to $\Bbb P^3$: this is only true for smooth curves. 2. What does that condition $\min(p,q,r)=0$ mean? Are you sure you've copied this down from the book correctly? 3. Can you give a page number for the specific section you're working out of? In my copy chapter 1 section 4 is about the Kodaira embedding theorem, which is not what you're talking about here.

Comment: Ok I've made a mistake in copying down from the book, I have just edited.

Comment: Why do the conditions look obscure? As I explained, you're considering all points $r$ so that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are collinear, so this gives you the line spanned by $p$ and $q$. Taking the union over all $p\ne q$ gives you all the chords, and taking the closure gives you the locus of tangent lines as $p$ varies. (Here is where smoothness is used.)